# Does earthquake destroy buildings?

Tags: dont-starve

I think about moving base to underground but am afraid of the earthquakes. Will they destroy my structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, your structures are completely safe.

Earthquakes are generally speaking your friends: you get a lot of free resources that are generally not-renewable, were it not for earthquakes.

They are dangerous to your pets, or to you while you're being attacked.